# How to get nth last in list?

Tags: python, list

I know how to get the last item in a list `myList`:

`myList[-1]`

But how would I get the second last, or the nth last item in a string, without doing something like this:

`myList[len(myList)-(n-1)`

Comment: `myList[-2]`…!? If `2` is a variable, `-n`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second last would be  myList[-2], nth last is myList[-n]
You can read about negative indexing [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/)

Answer (score 3):

You can just keep using the reverse index.

```
# Second to list
myList[-2]

# n last
n=3
myList[-3]
```

In the second case, it would return the third from last.  You can also iterate over the list using this

```
for item in myList[::-1]:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase your negative index to count back from the end of a list

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l[-1]
5
>>> l[-2]
4
>>> l[-3]
3
```